# Are revenge and punishment allowed in hinduism?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, dharma

In Mahabharata, Shree krishna tells Arjuna to destroy his enemies and brothers. He reminds Arjuna of how draupadi was insulted and everything. He tells that punishing the sinful is the duty of Kshatriyas and it's not sin. If so, can someone take revenge and punish someone who has done some wrong things? should a person be blamed if he punishes the corrupt group of people in society?

Comment: Can you pls.quote the respective passages of Mahabharata  in your question, from which you came to know about discussion of Lord Krishna and Arjuna.

Comment: I would request you kindly go through the answer (Rickross) very carefully and ask if you have any doubt, do not take action before understanding. what Lord Krishna did that time is not good in KalYuga, because they were warrior, it was their dharma, Now its government's Dharma, go to police, fight legally.

Comment: One must remember that in Dwapara, kshatriyas were the government. kshatAt trAyate iti kshatriyaH (a kshatriya is one who protects from injury). So,the government must protect the meek and confer justice on society. Law & order require conviction for crimes. If the government does not establish law & order by punishing the wrong-doers, then anarchy will prevail and the just & the meek suffer. The sin of making such people suffer goes to the rulers. A king's account of sins gets incremented for every sin his subjects commit. So, a king/ruler must establish & preserve dharma even if by force.

Comment: i have remembered those passage from mahabharata krisna arjun discussion videos, not book. and i was just asking this for general knowledge.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If so, can someone take revenge and punish someone who has done some
>   wrong things? should a person be blamed if he punishes the corrupt
>   group of people in society?

Taking revenge and to punish someone are not exactly one and the same thing. Wrong doers should always be punished. To not punish them is again a blameable act.

Here are some verses from the Manu Smriti that talk about the need for punishment.

> Manu Smriti 7.22. **The whole world is kept in order by punishment**, for
>   a guiltless man is hard to find; through fear of punishment the whole
>   world yields the enjoyments (which it owes)
>
> Manu Smriti 7.23. **The gods, the Danavas, the Gandharvas, the
>   Rakshasas, the bird and snake deities even give the enjoyments (due
>   from them) only, if they are tormented by (the fear of) punishment.**
>
> Manu Smriti 7.14. For the (king’s) sake the Lord formerly created his
>   own son, Punishment, the protector of all creatures, (an incarnation
>   of) the law, formed of Brahman’s glory.

And, its the duty of the king to execute punishments. A king who does not punish the wicked sinks to the lower worlds.

> Manu Smriti 7.16. Having fully considered the time and the place (of
>   the offence), the strength and the knowledge (of the offender), let
>   him justly inflict that (punishment) on men who act unjustly.
>
> 7.18. Punishment alone governs all created beings, punishment alone protects them, punishment watches over them while they sleep; the wise
>   declare punishment (to be identical with) the law.
>
> 7.19. **If (punishment) is properly inflicted after (due) consideration, it makes all people happy;** but inflicted without consideration, it
>   destroys everything.
>
> 7.20. **If the king did not, without tiring, inflict punishment on those worthy to be punished, the stronger would roast the weaker, like fish
>   on a spit;**

Taking revenge, on the other hand, is not considered as a good attribute.

> If external or spiritual pain is created by others, and one is not
>   offended and does not wreak revenge, it (i.e., the spirit) is called
>   Dama. (39)
>
> **Atri Smriti, Chapter 1, Verse 39.**

And, Dama, Dana (charity), Aspriha (want of desire), Daya (mercy), Soucha (cleanliness) etc are considered as some auspicious traits or Mangala for all householders. So, a vengeful temperament is not at all praised in Scriptures.

Comment: This is an awesome answer