# Difference between giving curse and taking revenge

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, curse, dronacharya, ashwatthama

There are several revenge stories in Mahabaratha such as between Drona and Drupada.

Similarly there are many curse giving scenarios in Mahabaratha such as Krishna giving curse to Ashwatthama as well as one of his wife.

Taking revenge is a [bad conduct](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17573/is-taking-revenge-not-a-sin) but curse is not. What is the difference between both? Cursing and taking revenge are both for the bad actions done by others and are harming others.

Answer (score 5):

> Taking revenge is a bad conduct but curse is not. What is the
>   difference between both?

It is not that cursing is considered by the scriptures as a highly recommended act. It is definitely not so. It is considered as **immoral**.

As per Harita (the author of Harita Smriti - one of the 18 Smritis), it is a minor sin leading to loss of cast (Jatibhramsa).

See the following passage from Apasthambha Dharma Sutras 1.29.11:

> That is false,’ says Ha¯rita.  wife is comparable to a curdpot, for if
>   someone were to put impure milk into a curd-pot and mix in the
>   curdling substance, that curd cannot be used for ritual purposes. In
>   like manner, there can be no association with what is produced by the
>   semen of a sordid man* (cf. B
>   2.2.18–24).  **Sorcery and cursing make a man sordid but do not cause loss of caste. They do cause loss of caste,’ says Harita**

So, one who's cursing is bound to face some negative consequences later in their life or in next lives.

Comment: What does the last line of the passage mean, it says "do not cause loss of caste" but immediately is followed by "they do cause loss of caste"?

Comment: That is showing a difference of opinion. According to some the act is condemned but does not cause loss of caste. According to Harita, however, it does. @ChinmaySarupria

Comment: So in that way the text is upholding eventually what Harita has said. Such way of stating something is found in many Smritis. @ChinmaySarupria